# Forcing a CSS @media query in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design

I'm using **Twitter Bootstrap** to build a mobile website and was wondering.

Is there a way to force Firefox (or another browser, I don't mind) to use the specific `@media query` for a mobile device, without having to actually re-size the browser to e.g. 320x480px?

Basically, I want the browser to act like it's max-width is 320px but to have it fully maximised (to make it easier to use Firebug etc).

I've tried looking for add-ons, but haven't been able to find anything.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<iframe height="480" width="320" src="mobilepage.html"></iframe>`

Comment: Knew there'd be a simple solution! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firefox 15 (which you should be, since that's the supported version), see http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/06/new-firefox-developer-tools-will-help-you-build-responsive-websites/

Comment: Thanks Boris, hadn't noticed these new tools before. I'd previously been using the Web Developer Toolbar add-on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the chrome developer tools to emulate a device's size:

[image: chrome developer tools device metrics emulation]

Comment: If the image does not appear, then please post a comment. Then I will update the image as soon as I am on a network that allows me to.

Answer (score -1):

I use **Adobe Shadow**. it's a good tool.

Take a look here: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/shadow.html